# C++ | Set dynamic memory to variable?

Tags: c++

Can I assign dynamic memory or allocation to a variable instead of  pointer? like `int my_var= new int` and also delete it later?

Comment: Isn't a pointer a variable? Guess you need to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory allocation is taken care if you just write :

```
int n = 45;
```

but when using dynamic allocation, you have to use pointer and new operator, so that it can be deleted later:

```
int * foo;
foo = new int [5];
```

If you dont want your program to terminated during allocation due to some exception, try using nothrow. example:

```
int * foo;
foo = new (nothrow) int [5];
if (foo == nullptr) {
// error assigning memory. Take measures. 
}
```

using nothrow the pointer returned by new is a null pointer, and the program continues its execution normally.

Comment: Excellent answer, particularly the `new (nothrow)` detail.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. `new int` returns an `int*` and the behaviour on casting it to `int` is undefined.

If you dislike explicit pointers, you could write `typedef int* int_ptr;` and use `int_ptr my_var = new int;`

And yes, you **must** `delete my_var` at some point.